# How can I count words in an observation in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to count the words occurring in an observation. Some observations have only one word, but others have more than one and are separated by "/".

Here is a data set for a reproducible example.

```
data.1 <-read.csv(text = "
obs, a
2, date
3, Ari
4, MO
5, date/Ari
6, date/MO
7, Ari/MO
8, date/Ari/MO
")
```

This is the solution I came up with. But this solution is not counting correctly those observations with only one word.

```
data.2 <-  data.1 %>% 
              mutate(n.words = lengths(gregexpr("/", a)) + 1)
```

This is the output

[image]

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
lengths(strsplit(as.character(data.1$a),"/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_count` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data.1 %>% 
    mutate(n.words = str_count(a, "\\w+"))
```